# Weird Struct Behaviour

Tags: c#, struct

I wrote a little code snippet to demonstrate the issue. 
The problem is that when I declare a struct with the `Layout.Explicit` state,
it assigns an undefined value to the fields of that struct depending on the other value.
This issue only occurs when using the `Layout.Explicit` state.
it is pretty hard to explain without code so here is a short sample.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace ConsoleStruct
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        struct TestStruct
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public double dbl;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public ulong uu;
        }

        public static void SimpleMethod()
        {
            TestStruct st;
            st.uu = 0;
            st.dbl = 5000.0;
            Console.WriteLine(st.uu.ToString()); // ==> uu becomes 4662219572839972864 
                                                 //instead of 0 :(
                                                 // it looks like the value of uu is dependent on the 
                                                 //value assigned to dbl
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SimpleMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody please explain to me why this is happening.
Using VS 2013.
Thanks.

Comment: Well yes, that's precisely the point of defining fields with the same FieldOffset, they overlap because you *explicitly requested it*

Comment: Hm, not sure what the misunderstanding is here. What do you think `[FieldOffset(0)]` does? What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it looks like the value of uu is dependent on the value assigned to dbl

Yes it is. Because you gave them the same offsets, they occupy the same place in memory (inside the struct).

`[FieldOffset(...)]` lets you layout the fields manually and you can make them overlap. Some unmanaged APIs require that.

Note that when you try overlap something with a reference field (like a string) you will get a runtime exception. Memory safety can only be upheld as long as you do this with value types only.

Comment: So just to make it clear, to fix this, would he have to change the attribute FieldOffset of `uu` to `1`? or `sizeof(double)`? or what's the general idea of FieldOffset

Comment: You would have to raise it to `sizeof(double)`. There may be other platform constraints (alignment). The general idea is to map out a struct exactly, usually to match a foreign specification.

Comment: Ok, so you assured what I thought, that FieldOffset takes byte to offset. Thanks

Comment: @HenkHolterman what are the usecases to overlap, and what is the maximum value of `LayoutOffset` that can be used, what does it actually means? any reference link to read would be helpful.

Comment: The use-case are the unmanaged APIs. If you don't need this, don't spend any time on it. It's not for 'normal' programming. Although you could build a very fast long-to-2-int converter this way.